# What do scriptures say about lucid dreaming?

Tags: dream

There are 4 states of consciousness - waking, dreaming, dreamless and Turiya although some people do refer to 5th state called [Turiyatita](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8993/3872). According to Adi Shankara, dreams are [created by Jiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14597/3872).

Brihadaranyaka Upanishad IV.3.9 -

> He himself destroying, he himself shaping dreams with his own splendour, with his own light.

There is a type of dream known as lucid dream. According to Wiki:

> **A lucid dream is a dream during which the dreamer is aware of dreaming**. During lucid dreaming, the dreamer may be able to exert some degree of control over the dream characters, narrative, and environment.

This is the difference between normal dreams and lucid dreams, in normal dreams, dreamer has no control over environments and objects but in lucid dreaming, the dreamer decides what to do next!

Dreamer might want to go on a solar system trip or a visit to Betelgeuse which is 700 light years away. Dreamer can fly like a free bird or dive in the ocean like Godzilla!
There are a lot of experts in this field who have years of experience in lucid dreaming and according to research, most people experience atleast 1 lucid dream in their life.

But do scriptures contain anything about it? As far as I know, Upanishads talk about dreaming state but not sub type of it.

Comment: Shaiva scriptures subdivides these states. And for lucid dreaming, Malinivijay Tantra says- "When  during  the  entire  phantasmagoria  of  his  dream  state, the  dreamer  does  not  lose  hold  of  his  self-consciousness,  when  he is  fully  aware  of  himself  and  knows  that  he  is  only  dreaming, then  this  state  is  known  as  svapna-turya.  This  is  also  called susamahita  state,  because  in  this  state  the  dreamer  is  a  fully integrated  individual. "

Comment: I think the phenomenon of Lucid Dreaming proves that dreams are created by Jeeva...

Comment: @Tezz Well the Jeeva doesn't have complete control, just enough to nudge the world in a direction, just like they do in the waking world.