# Do Dvaitins, Vishistadvaitins and Achintya-Bheda-Abheda-vaadins consider the dream world as real?

Tags: vedanta, vishishtadvaita, dvaita, achintya-bheda-abheda

Please note that this is not an attack on Dvaita, Vishistadvaita and Achintya-Bheda-Abheda. This is information seeking question.

We know the famous analogy of the universe compared with a dream in Advaita. This claim is refused by Dvaita, Vishishtadvaita and Achintya-Bheda-Abheda .

So I was just curious whether these schools consider our dreams to be an illusion or a reality. What is their stance on dream state?

What is the dream experienced by a person after he wakes. What is the dream to him according to dualistic schools. If you can please include some references so that authenticity of the answer is established. You can answer from any one's school's point of view.

Comment: Add Achintya-Bheda-Abheda also.

Comment: @Surya yes Vishistadvaitha is there no. Isn't it the same thing? Vishistadvaitha is bhedabheda.

Comment: Achintya-Bheda-Abheda is slightly different than Vishishtadvaita actually. @Chakrapani N Rao

Comment: OK , I'm adding it, but can you, for my knowledge, tell me in short, what is the core difference bw ABA and VA?

Comment: Well, they consider the experience and knowledge of dream state is real. Visit closely related post [Are dreams created by Jivatma or Paramatma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14597/277) Where Vishisthadvaita and Dvaita agree on dreams are created by supreme self, not by individual self as said by Advaita.

Comment: @Pandya ok they consider the experience of dream state to be real, but whether the dream itself is real or not according to them.

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao I don't know much about it. Refer [this section](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe48/sbe48029.htm) of Sri Bhashya.

Comment: @Pandya Thank you

Comment: @ChakrapaniNRao I'm not good at explaining them well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dream states are indeed real and carry some meaning according to the Govinda bhashya of Baladeva Vidyabhushana of the Gaudiya Vaishnava school(representing Acintya bhedābheda) on the Brahma sutras as they are perceived and inspired by Brahman, although temporary. Here are some attached pages from the relevant sections: [image][image][image]